# Open raw drive without formatting

Tags: virtualbox, filesystems, raw

I have a disk from a laptop that died.

The disk is functioning correctly and not broken, but it is in RAW file system format and I cannot open it from windows.

I have tried mounting it in a virtual machine with virtualbox but i get an access denied error.

My question is how can I get the files from this drive.Any method is acceptable, file recovery software, formatting to NFTS without erasing data or mounting it on a linux system in a VM

Comment: You could try something like HxD to read the data (or even manually rebuild the header tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using 
[Test Disk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to open the disk through the console with the help of [This](http://html5.litten.com/updated-how-to-fix-external-disk-drive-suddenly-became-raw/) article.

Then I just copied the important files to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot [Hiren's BootCD](http://hirensbootcd.org) and use Mini WindowsXP to easily copy files from your old drive to new location (i.e. external HDD).